# Centos 8 Invalid command '<VirtualHost*:80', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2

I am currently on a vps to which I have directed 9 domain name.
in httpd.conf file
I inserted this

```
       <VirtualHost*:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/non.com
    ServerName non.com
    ServerAlias www.non.com
    <Directory "/var/www/non.com">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride    </Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://non.com:443/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost*:80>
<VirtualHost*:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ne.com
    ServerName ne.com
    <Directory  "/var/www/ne.com">
         Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://ne.com:443/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost*:80>`
```

i have allways the same probleme

AH00526: Syntax error on line 349 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command '<VirtualHost*:80', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

thank you for help

Comment: Which one of those is line 349?

Answer (score 0):

There is a space missing between the t and the * in the open tag and you close the tag without the host:port part.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/non.com
  ServerName non.com
  ServerAlias www.non.com
  <Directory "/var/www/non.com">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride    
  </Directory>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://non.com:443/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost*:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/ne.com
  ServerName ne.com
  <Directory  "/var/www/ne.com">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://ne.com:443/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```